# How can I update Android Studio to the latest version?

Tags: android-studio

I have just downloaded and installed Android Studio. Right after it starts for the first time, it displays the following dialog:

[image]

Apparently, the installer from the website only installed 0.2.0. When I click **More Info...**, it just sends me to http://tools.android.com/recent where there's no download link for me to find.

So, where do I get the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I would get a completely different dialog on another machine.

[image]

The machine where I noticed the problem was connected to the internet via cable and the WiFi was turned off. As soon as I turned on the WiFi, I would get the same update dialog.